# Extracting drought values below -1 for at least three consecutive months

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am a novice with programming, and I can't seem to get around this issue, or if I'm even on the right track. The goal is to model land use change after periods of drought using precipitation data and land use data in GEE.

I have global SPEI values (drought index), where I want to define a drought when a pixel value falls *below -1 for at least three consecutive months.* I am only able to create a layer where it has got below -1 for any period of the year. So I need to "filter" out the data based on the three months boundary. This is how far I can get:

```
var filtered_threshold = function(image){
return image.updateMask((image.lt(-1))).toInt();  //image.mask().and
}
var SPEI_threshold = SPEI.map(filtered_threshold)
print(SPEI_threshold, 'SPEI image below -1');
Map.addLayer(SPEI_threshold,visParams , 'SPEI for the whole year (at some point?) below -1')
```

Comment: See: https://medium.com/google-earth/runs-with-arrays-400de937510a

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an SPI product to test, and I don't know if there is an implementation of a roll sum or something equivalent, but you can convert the collection to a list, and then compute if the condition meets your requirement.

For example, I'll take some monthly data and compute "drought index" if the precipitation is less than 10 mm/month (yes, I know SPI is totally different, but it's an example):

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY");

function droughtMask(img){
  return img.expression('b("total_precipitation") < 0.01 ? 1 : 0')
  .rename('drought');
}

var maskedCol = imageCollection.map(droughtMask);
```

The expression here is `condition ? true : false`. Then, create an index sequence for iterating the collection (here, the first 100 records), sum the masked values and evaluate the condition:

```
var counter = ee.List.sequence(0,100-3);

function getCondition(index){
  var colList = maskedCol.toList(3, index);
  var imgSum = ee.Image(ee.List(colList).get(0)).add(ee.Image(ee.List(colList).get(1))).add(ee.Image(ee.List(colList).get(2))).rename("sum")
  return imgSum.expression('b("sum") == 3 ? 1 : 0')
}

var results = counter.map(getCondition);
```

For getting back an image collection, flatten the results and create it:

```
var finalCol = ee.ImageCollection(results.flatten());
```